# Inherit Cache options in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

The .htaccess on my root folder contains the following code which mostly deals with cache expirations:

```
# Disable Etags
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

# Expires
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
Header unset Last-Modified
Header set Cache-Control "public"

<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi|html?)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
ExpiresDefault A0

ExpiresActive Off
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch ".(css|js)$">
Header set Expires "access plus 1 day"
</FilesMatch>

# Enable Compresion
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm currently copy pasting the code in folders inside the root. How can I inherit this configuration on an .htaccess located on a folder just inside the root?